# Power meter zero-offset calibration

Tags: laser, power

I have to measure the output power of a laser diode. To this aim, I am going to use an integrating sphere connected to a photodetector and a power meter. 
Concerning the photodetector, electrical offset in the amplifier circuitry can be present. The offset can be removed by doing a zero-offset calibration of the power meter.

My question is, during the measurement when can I understand that I need to do a zero-offset calibration to the power meter?